# SQL Schema Design: Associated with many tables?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, database-schema

Lets say I have a database with 4 types of things in it: Neighborhood, City, Houses, and Comment, like so

City:
        name
        ID

```
Neighborhood:
    name
    ID
    CityID (foreign key to City:ID)

House:
    name
    ID
    NeighborhoodID (foreign key to Neighborhood:ID)
    CityID (foreign key to City:ID)

Comment:
    ID
    Text
    ???? (key to the subject of the comment)
```

I want users to be able to comment on a City, a Neighborhood or a House. How do I express this relationship in SQL?

One idea I had was to create 3 one to many relationship tables:

```
CommentToCity:
    commentID
    cityID
```

then when fetching the list of Cities, I could do a join on this table as well to get the related comments. I would then create a similar situation for House and Neighborhood.

Another idea would be to have globally unique identifiers in City, House and Neighborhood, and then have that global ID be the foreign key in the comment. Then when fetching the City it would do a join on comments looking for that global ID.

Are either of these a good way? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Add a commentID to City, Neighborhood And House. (foreign key to comment:Id)

This way you just create an empty comment and add its Id if there is no comment on something.